# CodeIgniter project move from localserver to googlecloud

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

My codeigniter project on version 2 working well in Linux hosting but when i upload this project on google cloud i got error.
 When i load the database in autoload.php

```
   $autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

another project on core php working very well

```
   $this->con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","alex_quiz");
```

Comment: _"i got error"_ - What error? Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to change your **databse.php** file according to your db host. If not can you **post error** it will help to identify the error.

[image: databse.php]

Comment: the same configuration working in core php code, but not in codeigniter ,if bug in config then why it work for core php. there is no error log create .